# unable to call external typescript function from phaser events in Ionic2

Tags: ionic2, phaser-framework

I am working on Ionic2 + Phaserjs.

I have created the Phaser canvas and load sprite in it. Now I want to add drag event on sprite and call a typescript function in that drag event. But my problem is that Phaser reserve the 'this' keyword for its own scope so I cant call the external typescript function like this.sayHello().

```
create() { // this is Phaser.create function
//console.log(vv)
this.counter = 0;
this.game.scale.scaleMode = Phaser.ScaleManager.SHOW_ALL;
this.game.stage.backgroundColor = "#4488AA";
console.log("hellow");
this.logo = this.game.add.sprite(this.game.world.centerX, this.game.world.centerY, 'logo');
this.logo.anchor.setTo(0.5, 0.5);
this.logo.scale.setTo(.5);
this.logo.inputEnabled = true;
this.logo.input.enableDrag();
// this.logo.events.onDragStart.add(this.openHyperlink(), this);        
}

this.openHyperlink = function(){
  console.log(this.mainApp)
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you declare your typescript function use the arrow notation
example :

```
sayHello = () => { console.log('Hi');
                   this.something(); //here this is the original this object
                 };
```

As the arrow notation with TypeScript keeps the original this object

Comment: Thanks, i did the same with phaser.create / preload function and it works